FastAPI required discriminated union tags
Imagine I have a Pydantic model with a discriminative union:
class Cat(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['cat'] = 'cat'
    meows: int


class Dog(BaseModel):
    pet_type: Literal['dog'] = 'dog'
    barks: float

class PetCollection(BaseModel):
    pet: Union[Cat, Dog] = Field(..., discriminator='pet_type')
    n: int

Because I'm lazy, I give pet_type fields default values so that I don't have to manually provide them when constructing the objects on the Python side.
Now, I create a simple FastAPI GET endpoint that returns a PetCollection. As it is now, the generated OpenAPI schema says that the pet_type field in the Cat and Dog schemas is not required. But in practice it is required, in the sense that every Cat and every Dog my API returns will have a pet_type field set.
(My particular annoyance is that when I generate typescript bindings from the schema, I can't use exhaustive pattern matching on pet_type. But I'm sure this has other annoying consequences.)
What's the best way to improve this? The alternatives I see are:

Just don't set the default values in the model definitions, and write the arg manually every time I construct a Cat or a Dog
Write a fancy metaclass that, while keeping the pet_type field required, will redefine init to auto-provide the default pet_type. (But then can I make mypy and pylance infer type annotations of this hacked constructor?)
Some obvious solution I'm not aware of

Thanks!
